# Handle Node uncaughtException and close connection

Tags: node.js

In order to not crash a server, we catch any uncaught exception in main.js.  However, the request does not terminate then. Is there a way to terminate the active request?

```
//keep server from crashing by catching all exceptions not caught before
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    //kill request that caused the error
});

//launch server
https.createServer(options, app).listen(appSettings.ports.https, function(){
    console.log('Express https server listening on port %d in %s mode',appSettings.ports.https, app.settings.env);
});
```

Comment: You should probably catch your exceptions in the context where you can access the request.

Comment: Seconded, but also this is what domains where created for.

Comment: New to Node. What do you mean by domains?

Comment: [Here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/domain.html) is the documentation on domains.